# Characterization of dimension in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I have some problem, which I thought, is already solved on this website, but I couldn't find it.

Let $H$ be a real, nonzero Hilbert space, and let $E$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$. Denote $V:=\left\{ h\in H \ : \ \Vert h-e\Vert =\Vert h-e'\Vert, \ \ \   e,e'\in E\right\}$.
Show that $V=\left\{0\right\}$ iff $\dim H=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\dim H =n< +\infty$.

Define $h= \sum_{k=1}^n e_k \ne 0$.

Then: $$\left\|\sum_{k\ne i} e_k\right\|^2 = n - 1 = \left\|\sum_{k\ne j} e_k\right\|^2, \quad \forall j\in\{1, \ldots, n\}$$

Hence $h \in V$.

Conversely, assume $0 \ne h \in V$.$\newcommand\inner[2]{\left\langle #1, #2 \right\rangle}$

For any $e, e' \in E$ we have:
$$\|h - e\|^2 = \|h - e'\|^2 \implies \inner{h-e}{h-e} = \inner{h-e'}{h-e'}$$

From here we obtain $$\Re\inner{h}{e} = \Re\inner{h}{e'}$$

Let $E = \{e_j : j \in J\}$.
$$h = \sum_{j \in J}\inner{h}{e_j} e_j \implies \|h\|^2 = \sum_{j \in J}\left|\inner{h}{e_j}\right|^2 \geq \sum_{j \in J}\left(\Re\inner{h}{e_j}\right)^2$$

where $\Re\inner{h}{e_j}$ are equal for every $j \in J$.

$h \ne 0$ implies $\|h\| \ne 0$ so $\inner{h}{e_i} \ne 0$, for some $i \in J$. $H$ is real so in fact we have $\Re\inner{h}{e_j} \ne 0$.

Since $\|h\| < +\infty$, we get that $J$ must be finite.

Hence, $\dim H < +\infty$.

Comment: now its clear, thank u ;)

Comment: one more question, yesterday I didn't see it. i'm confused with the first implication and with the indexes $i,j,k's$. Can you explain it in the easier way?

Comment: @Yelon I messed them up a bit. 
Let $E = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$. Take $i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, i\ne j$. Using the Pythagorean theorem we have:
\begin{align}
\left\|\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne_k\right)-e_i\right\|^2 &= \|e_1 + \ldots + e_{i-1}+e_{i+1}+\ldots+e_n\|^2 \\
&= \|e_1\|^2 + \ldots + \|e_{i-1}\|^2+\|e_{i+1}\|^2+\ldots+\|e_n\|^2\\
&= n-1\\
&= \|e_1\|^2 + \ldots + \|e_{j-1}\|^2+\|e_{j+1}\|^2+\ldots+\|e_n\|^2\\
&= \|e_1 + \ldots + e_{j-1}+e_{j+1}+\ldots+e_n\|^2 \\
&= \left\|\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne_k\right)-e_j\right\|^2
\end{align}

Comment: Notice that if $\dim H = +\infty$, the sum $\sum_{j\in J} e_j$ does not converge since we would have $$\left\|\sum_{j\in J} e_j\right\|^2 = \sum_{j\in J}1 = +\infty$$

Comment: ok I see :) thanks :)